# header() in php is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm very new in PHP and please don't mark this question as duplicate, because I've searched and found many solutions on stackoverflow as well as other sites, here is the code in my login.php what I'm trying to do is pass some data to controller.php:

```
 window.onload = function(){
$('#btnLogin').click(function() {
var val1 = $('#txtusername').val();
var val2 = $('#txtpassword').val();
var val3 = "login";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'controller.php',
    data: { action: val3, username: val1, password: val2 },
    success: function(response) {
    alert(response);    
    }
});
});
}
```

It is working well if I don't want to navigate to another page "index.php" because in controller.php I've received all data what passed from login.php, but the header("Location: index.php") is not working.Bellow is my controller.php:

```
<?php
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
?>
```

I've tried some solutions like: "delete blank spaces",add "error_reporting(E_ALL)" and "ini_set('display_errors', 'On') " and "ob_start()" to the top of the controller.php file, but nothing better happen.

Comment: Is there any whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag, or is there any output coming from other files before you include that _"controller"_ file? If so: headers are already sent, so you can't set them. Also: if a file contains only PHP code, it's recommended you omit the closing `?>` tag

Comment: Are you trying to redirect using an ajax call?

Comment: You have to use `window.location.replace("your_url");`  in your JavaScript

Comment: Elias Van Ootegem: thanks, there is no whitespace before the opening <?php tag and there is no output coming from other files before I include that "controller" file and I sent nothing to other page before I call the header();

Comment: Khaled: could you please explain your answer in more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that via ajax request. If you want to navigate to `index.php` after you finish processing data via `controller.php` use jquery redirection inside your success response.

```
success: function(response) {
    window.location.replace("index.php");   
}
```

Comment: Mahfuzul Alam: I've tried your solution before, it works, but the response is a HTML page if i print it out.I just wanna send a response back to login.php by used echo "OK"; but go with "OK" the login.php received an HTML response text, so is it possible for me to receive only "OK" from response text?

Comment: Sure you can get 'OK' response. `<?php return 'OK'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing your redirect in ajax request. This will not redirect your page, it will only redirect the ajax request. Instead return some json response and check this response in the ajax callback and then redirect the user using javascript.